# Juggling Layout Managers

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I am struggling with the z-order drawing pattern of swing. I have two methods that both draw on one panel. One method draws essentially the background, things that aren't moving, the other draws things that will change on screen. In my main method I want to draw the still parts, then draw everything that moves on top of that. I'm essentially using a while(true) loop while the game is playing, so I cant call the `drawMoving` method before the `drawStill` method without needlessly updating the still images every tick. On top of this I'm using a `CardLayout` to display various panels, and the panels are using `GridBag`.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Show us code and tell us what isn't working.  Z-order is normally only used internally by Swing, you don't have to mess with it, especially if you're just using regular layout managers like CardLayout or GridBag.

Comment: If I use CardLayout's show to display a panel, how can I display the JLayeredPane which contains 2 JPanels (one of the still images, one of the moving images)